# Snowflake: getting value from inner tags of xml file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to import xml file into snowflake database table. I created a table and XML file format. The XML file format is created using following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT LAND_XML.PUBLIC.XML_FILE_FORMAT 
TYPE = 'XML' 
COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
PRESERVE_SPACE = FALSE 
STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE 
DISABLE_SNOWFLAKE_DATA = FALSE 
DISABLE_AUTO_CONVERT = FALSE 
IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS = FALSE;
```

The XML file looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NoticeOfChange version="1.0.0" application_version="v0.0.1-5780-g16dbd00e9"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://prod.notices.govt/notices/">
    <ProducedBy>
        <Name>Land Department</Name>
        <Contact>
            <Name>Technical Support</Name>
            <Phone>0800 xxx xxx</Phone>
            <Email>customersupport@land.govt</Email>
        </Contact>
    </ProducedBy>
    <Notices>
    <Notice>
            <NoticeId>577</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
   <Notice>
            <NoticeId>578</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
    <Notice>
            <NoticeId>579</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
   <Notice>
            <NoticeId>580</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
   </Notices>
</NoticeOfChange>
```

When I imported XML file into snowflake database table, it showed only two rows (instead of expected 4 rows of notices). The output is shown in the following picture:
[image]

The current file format split the XML file into two rows based on `<produced by>` and `<notices>` tag. However, I am not interested in `<produced by>` tag (want to discard it) and want to convert no of notices present in `<notices>` tag into separate row of the table. Based on limited knowledge, I could not modify the file format into desired output I want. Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root object is `NoticeOfChange` so flattening on that would give you the objects of that, `ProducedBy` and `Notices`, as you note, you just want the latter, so flatten that sub object.. via `xmlget(d.xml, 'Notices'):"$"`

So using this CTE just for the data..

```
WITH data_table AS (
    SELECT PARSE_XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NoticeOfChange version="1.0.0" application_version="v0.0.1-5780-g16dbd00e9"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://prod.notices.govt/notices/">
    <ProducedBy>
        <Name>Land Department</Name>
        <Contact>
            <Name>Technical Support</Name>
            <Phone>0800 xxx xxx</Phone>
            <Email>customersupport@land.govt</Email>
        </Contact>
    </ProducedBy>
    <Notices>
    <Notice>
            <NoticeId>577</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
   <Notice>
            <NoticeId>578</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
    <Notice>
            <NoticeId>579</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
   <Notice>
            <NoticeId>580</NoticeId>
            <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType>
            <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description>
            <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory>
   </Notice>
   </Notices>
</NoticeOfChange>') as xml
)
```

Accessing the Notices is done via:

```
SELECT 
    f.value as notice
FROM data_table AS d
    ,lateral flatten(input=>xmlget(d.xml, 'Notices'):"$")f;
```

giving:

| NOTICE |
| --- |
| <Notice> <NoticeId>577</NoticeId> <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType> <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description> <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory> </Notice> |
| <Notice> <NoticeId>578</NoticeId> <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType> <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description> <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory> </Notice> |
| <Notice> <NoticeId>579</NoticeId> <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType> <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description> <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory> </Notice> |
| <Notice> <NoticeId>580</NoticeId> <NoticeType>NoticeOfChange</NoticeType> <Description>Notification of change of ownership of rating unit</Description> <Statutory>Under Local Government (Rating) Act 2020</Statutory> </Notice> |

At which point to can store or access the induvial parts as you need.